# Limit of the sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt{n}+2/\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a way mathematically to prove this limit without using de l'hopital because I think I can't use it on sequences. I know I can say that the log function goes to infinity slower than the denominator but is that the only way I can prove this?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt{n}+2/\sqrt{n}}=0}$$

Comment: Saying "the log function goes to infinity slower than the denominator" is definitely the best thing and the fastest solution

Comment: The sequence is dominated by $\frac {3 \ln n} {\sqrt n}$.

Comment: @SineoftheTime: it is better to state this in the form of a well known / standard limit formula $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\log x) ^a} {x^b} =0$$ for any positive $a, b $. The formula is a direct consequence of $\log x\leq x-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=\mathrm e^m$. Note that as $n\to\infty$, we also have $m\to\infty$. Hence, observing that $0 \leq \frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt{n}+2/\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{\log(n^3)}{\sqrt{n}}$,
$$0\le\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt{n}+2/\sqrt{n}}}\le\lim_{n \to \infty}3\frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{m \to \infty}3\frac{m}{\mathrm e^{m/2}}\le\lim_{m \to \infty}3\frac{m}{m^2/8}=0$$

observing that $\mathrm e^{x}>x^2/2,\, \forall x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $\sqrt{n}$ on the top and bottom: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt{n}+2/\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}\log(n^3-7)}{n+2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\left((n^3-7)^\sqrt{n}\right)}{n+2}$$Since $\log n$ doesn't approach $\infty$ as fast as $n$, this becomes zero.

Edit: As a note, don't try comparing derivatives between the numerators. That would take way too much time and effort.

Comment: What do you mean by "grows slower?"  And you have a product of terms

Comment: @MarkViola grows slower as in its rate of growth is slower. I will edit to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have for $n\ge2$

$$ \left|\frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt n+2/\sqrt n} \right|\le 3\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: I know this is trivial, but may you please explain how you did this? This would help other readers that are still new to Calculus.

Comment: I think this definition might have been used $$∀ε > 0 ∃ν ∈ N : |an − L| < ε  ∀n > ν$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = \frac{\log(n^3-7)}{\sqrt{n}+2/\sqrt{n}}$. Then
$$0 \leq a_n \leq \frac{\log(n^3)}{\sqrt{n}} = 3\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
So we may instead show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=0$ where
$$b_n = \frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}.$$ To show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=0$ note that for any $0 < p < 1$ we can bound
$$\log(n) = \int_1^n \frac{1}{x} \, dx \leq \int_1^n \frac{1}{x^p}\, dx = \frac{1}{1-p} (n^{1-p} - 1) \leq \frac{1}{1-p}n^{1-p}.$$
Setting, for example, $p=\frac34$, we have
$$\log(n) \leq 4 \sqrt[4]{n},$$
and so
$$0\leq b_n = \frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{4}{\sqrt[4]{n}},$$
from which it follows that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show that ${\log n\over \sqrt{n}}$ tends to $0,$ in order to finish the answer by @Mark Viola,  could be as follows. Let $16^k\le n< 16^{k+1}.$ Then $$\log n<(k+1)\log 16,\quad \sqrt{n}\ge 4^k$$ Hence $${\log n\over \sqrt{n}}\le \log 16\,{k+1\over 4^k}\le {4\log 2 \over 2^k} {k+1\over 2^k}\le {8\log 2 \over 2^{k+1}}\le {8\log 2 \over \sqrt[4]{n}}$$